# Is there a Salesforce sign-in that can be used for code

Tags: oauth2, single-sign-on

Does Salesforce provide a login method dialogue or window service that can be used within code? I'm looking for something much like the [Google Sign in](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) 
screen that can be integrated on the web or via a mobile app, expect for Java. Does anyone know if this exists?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [OAuth2.0 authentication flows](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_authenticate_overview.htm)?

Comment: Yes, it exists: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/identityImplGuide/external_identity_login_intro.htm

Answer (score 1):

There are many options for implementing SSO. Exactly how you'll want to do that will greatly depend on your organization, who you want to have as your identity provider (idP) and whether or not you use some kind of Active Directory Service in your company. You can declaratively customize your organization to do much of what you're asking about without needing to create any custom code by using Custom Apps and Web Services that Salesforce provides for you if you choose to use them as the the idP.

There are many great resources to learn about these options including webinars and documentation. What I'm going to do is refer you to the most helpful documentation that will provide you with links to other docs and resources so you can later come back and ask a new question that's more specific to your particular situation. Here's the list I'd refer you to:

- [Salesforce Identity](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Identity)
- [Identity Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.identityImplGuide.meta/identityImplGuide/)
- [Salesforce External Identity Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/)
- [Salesforce Security Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/)
- [Single Sign-On Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sso.meta/sso/)
- [Salesforce Help: Single Sign On](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_about.htm&type=0)

Yes, its a very deep and complex subject that will require a lot of research on your part. If you come back to ask questions, be sure to provide the level of detailed information someone will need to give you an answer without a lot of back & forth discovery.